# What is causing the expected literal error?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a query that has a syntax error. This is the error!

> string(63) "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected Literal,
>   got 'd'"

```
public function getDomain(string $country)
{
    try {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where(':country NOT IN (d.blocked_countries)')
            ->setParameter('country', $country)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult()
            ;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: What type blocked_countries is? Is this field type is array, json or relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, i made it like that because **-> setParameter** is safer

```
    {
        try {
            return  $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
                ->where('d.blocked_countries NOT LIKE :code')
                ->setParameter('code', "%$code%")
                ->setMaxResults(1)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult()
            ;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't apply `IN` operator for this case, because doctrine stores `array type` as string, with php `serialize()`. So you can do something like this

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
        $qb
            ->where(
                $qb->expr()->like('d.blocked_countries', "'%$country%'")
            )
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot but I made it through setParameter because it's safer!